# Запомнить предыдущий объект перед заменой, затем достать данные прежнего

Tags: javascript, видео

```
let l_time = video.currentTime, pause = video.paused, playbackRate = video.playbackRate;
video.src = '/video_360.mp4';
video.currentTime  = l_time;
video.playbackRate = playbackRate;
```

Работает, в чем тут дело? Делаю так

```
(def = video).src = '/video_360.mp4';
video.currentTime  = def.currentTime;
video.playbackRate = def.playbackRate;
```

Необходимо поменять ссылку на файл другого разрешения. Но для того, чтобы после смены файла, видео началось проигрываться с того же момента. Необходимо, поосле смены, задать тайм. В первом случаи работает, но почему не работает во втором? Запоминаем перед заменой ссылки предыдущий объект в стороннюю переменную. А затем вытаскиваем из нее, но в ней уже объект нового файла.

Толи что делаю не так, не понимаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы запоминаете не предыдущий объект, а **ссылку** на объект. Потому переменная `def` продолжает ссылаться на тот же объект. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-copy).

При копировании объекта некоторые свойства теряются. Тогда я просто предлагаю создавать отдельно объект `def` и записывать в него требуемые значения:

```js
const def = {
  currentTime: video.currentTime,
  playbackRate: video.playbackRate,
};

// ...
video.currentTime = def.currentTime;
video.playbackRate = def.playbackRate;
```

Comment: Не понимаю, вроде разобрался. Но def содержит пользовательские переменные которые ранее добавил к video. А currentTime и прочее, к примеру взять текущий тайм у видео, подобных переменных  нету...

Comment: Вы правы, не заметил. Исправил ответ. Решения лучше я, увы, не знаю